# Conversion from pytorch to onnx to tensorflow graph definition to tflite - TOCO failed - type check fail

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, pytorch, onnx

I have a simple network of two convolutional layers and one fully connected one defined in pytorch essentially as follows:

```
def __init__([...])
    [...]
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, channels_conv1, width_conv1)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(channels_conv1, channels_conv2, width_conv2)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_layer_size, 2)

def forward(self, x):
    x = functional.max_pool1d(functional.relu(self.conv1(x)), 2, stride=2)
    x = functional.max_pool1d(functional.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2, stride=2)
    x = x.view(-1, self.num_flat_features(x))
    x = functional.softmax(self.fc1(x))
    return x
```

I want to convert it to tflite. So first it is converted to onnx

```
torch.onnx.export(model, input, "net.onnx",
                  export_params=True,
                  input_names=['input'],
                  output_names=['output'],
                  verbose=true)
```

Then I convert the result to a tensorflow graph definition with `onnx-tf`. The resulting `net.pb` is ok as it produces the same output as the original with `prepare(onnx.load('net.onnx')).run(...)`.

However, I have two problems: a minor one is that the `net.pb` graph doesn't contain the output node anymore and I have to fish for the output node. 
The second is that when I try to perform the final conversion with

```
tflite_convert --output_file=net.tflite --graph_def_file=net.pb --input_arrays=input --output_arrays=Softmax
```

I get a TOCO failure at a type check:

```
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.
2018-11-16 16:11:37.592030: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1280] Converting unsupported operation: Where
2018-11-16 16:11:37.601384: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 61 operators, 113 arrays (0 quantized)
2018-11-16 16:11:37.602005: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 61 operators, 113 arrays (0 quantized)
2018-11-16 16:11:37.602311: F tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/resolve_constant_gather.cc:105] Check failed: coords_array.data_type == ArrayDataType::kInt32 Only int32 indices are supported
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried digging in the network but I can't seem to find the vexing object and I didn't find issues obviously related to this problem. Any pointer to a point where this process might have derailed would be a great!

```
tf-nightly==1.13.0.dev20181116
onnx==1.3.0
torch-nightly==1.0.0.dev201811
```

and `master` (commit `b5fef1b`) of [onnx-tensorflow](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow/commit/b5fef1b6471ad6c5bac214e9799c38d41658ee73)

Comment: Could it be linked to : https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7870 ?

Comment: I ran into the same issue as well. Try explicitly casting .view parameters to int